# SonarQube Proxy Configuration, Tricky

Tags: proxy, sonarqube

I cannot get the proxy configuration to work for SonarQube 4.0 so that I can install plugins.

When i open `http://localhost:9000/updatecenter/available` it displays the error: "Not connected to update center. Please check your internet connection and logs."

In sonar.log I read: "org.sonar.api.utils.HttpDownloader$HttpException: Fail to download [http://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties]. Response code: 403"

In sonar.properties I configured it with the same proxy which I use for other programs:

```
sonar.updatecenter.activate=true
http.proxyHost=<host>
http.proxyPort=<port>
http.proxyUser=<username>
http.proxyPassword=<password>
```

I tried the same to configure in wrapper.properties, but it didn't work either by the way.

For the proxy host I tried the short and the full name. For the username I tried just the username and with `<DOMAINNAME>\<username>` and `<DOMAINNAME>\\<username>`.

Nothing of it worked. Any ideas?

Comment: if your company uses NTLM type proxy, you can try to use CNTLM application. By using that you can bypass proxy.

Comment: I configured i like you did and it run smoothly. I used the IP of my proxy.

Comment: In SonarQube 5.1.1 proxy configuration should be done not in conf/wrapper.properties but in conf/sonar.properties. I've configured proxy there and can see list of plugins, but can't download nor update any plugin, because of error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23289159/sonar-does-not-download-plugins

Answer (score 10):

My proxy configuration works and looks the following way:

```
http.proxyHost=proxy.domain.de
http.proxyPort=8888
```

Note that there is no "http://" or anything else before the URL.

Also, I do not use proxy authentication, so I left "proxyUser" and "proxyPassword" commented out.

Answer (score 6):

For those running SonarQube in Docker, I had no luck with any suggestion mentioned here. But I found following solution that worked for me ([here](https://github.com/SonarSource/docker-sonarqube/issues/79)):

```
docker run -d sonarqube -Dhttp.proxyHost=<myproxy.url.com> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<port>
```

and equivalent of this in a docker-compose notation:

```
services:
  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube
    command: -Dhttp.proxyHost=<myproxy.url.com> -Dhttp.proxyPort=<port>
```

Comment: that totaly did the trick for our corporate proxy! Please note that to authenticate over Active directory you can specify a domain and user by excaping the backslash. e.g. : -Dhttp.proxyUser=DOMAIN\\username

Answer (score 4):

Just an information: I had this problem also.
I can see the PlugIns but cannot download it. The problem is, you have to add this line into your sonar.properties, for the https:

```
# https-proxy
sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts=-Dhttps.proxyHost=xxxxx -Dhttps.proxyPort=xxxx -Dhttps.proxyUser=xxxx -Dhttps.proxyPassword=xxxx
```

Comment: Didn't work for me.
Either by setting the options in "sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts" or directly.

Answer (score 4):

I used the official documentation and it works:
[Using the Update Center behind a Proxy](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE52/Update+Center#UpdateCenter-UsingtheUpdateCenterbehindaProxy)

```
http.proxyHost=<your.proxy.host>
http.proxyPort=<yout.proxy.port>
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

At sonar.properties set the proxy without "http://", only http.proxyHost=myproxy.domain.pt

Another suggestion is to also add this lines on wrapper.conf:

```
wrapper.java.additional.3=-Dhttp.proxySet=true
wrapper.java.additional.4=-Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxy.domain.pt
wrapper.java.additional.5=-Dhttp.proxyPort=myproxy.port
wrapper.java.additional.6=-Dhttps.proxyHost=myproxy.domain.pt
wrapper.java.additional.7=-Dhttps.proxyPort=myproxy.port
```

Careful if you have a docker volume, remove it before deploy the new one with this configuration, or otherwise it will keep the original configuration

Answer (score 0):

Appart from http, don't forget to set your http**s** proxy configuration in sonar.properties (update server is behind HTTPS):

```
https.proxyHost=<host>
https.proxyPort=<port>
https.proxyUser=<username>
https.proxyPassword=<password>
```