# How to install/update plugins through SonarQube behind a proxy?

Tags: proxy, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1.2

I have a SonarQube 5.1.2 installation, and I am trying to install and update some plugins, the server have no direct internet access, we have a proxy here, lets say http://1.1.2.3:9191/ is our proxy and we have user and password authentication. Well I have write the sonar.properties accord to the docs

```
http.proxyHost=10.1.2.3
http.proxyPort=9191
http.proxyUser=theuser
http.proxyPassword=thepassword
```

I go to the http://sonar.sub.domain:9000/updatecenter/updates and I can see the list of plugins and the updates, so I assume in this point the communication by proxy is OK.

But, when I try to update or install a plugin I have this error in the page (Notice the `no proxy` message).

```
Fail to download the plugin (scmsvn, version 1.2) from https://bintray.com/artifact/download/sonarsource/SonarQube/org/sonarsource/scm/svn/sonar-scm-svn-plugin/1.2/sonar-scm-svn-plugin-1.2.jar (error is : Fail to download: https://bintray.com/artifact/download/sonarsource/SonarQube/org/sonarsource/scm/svn/sonar-scm-svn-plugin/1.2/sonar-scm-svn-plugin-1.2.jar (no proxy))   [hide]
```

So I do debug logging and try and this appears in logs

```
2015.09.11 09:32:47 DEBUG web[o.s.a.u.HttpDownloader$BaseHttpDownloader$HttpInputSupplier] Download: http://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties (HTTP proxy: 1.1.2.3:9191)
2015.09.11 09:32:49 DEBUG web[o.s.a.u.HttpDownloader$BaseHttpDownloader$HttpInputSupplier] Download: https://bintray.com/artifact/download/sonarsource/SonarQube/org/sonarsource/scm/svn/sonar-scm-svn-plugin/1.2/sonar-scm-svn-plugin-1.2.jar (no proxy)
2015.09.11 09:33:10 DEBUG web[o.s.s.p.PluginDownloader] Fail to download the plugin (scmsvn, version 1.2) from https://bintray.com/artifact/download/sonarsource/SonarQube/org/sonarsource/scm/svn/sonar-scm-svn-plugin/1.2/sonar-scm-svn-plugin-1.2.jar (error is : Fail to download: https://bintray.com/artifact/download/sonarsource/SonarQube/org/sonarsource/scm/svn/sonar-scm-svn-plugin/1.2/sonar-scm-svn-plugin-1.2.jar (no proxy))
org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Fail to download: https://bintray.com/artifact/download/sonarsource/SonarQube/org/sonarsource/scm/svn/sonar-scm-svn-plugin/1.2/sonar-scm-svn-plugin-1.2.jar (no proxy)
...
```

And a lot of lines of StackTrace,

So, When it is trying to reaching the `update-center.properties` resource there is no problem and it goes through proxy as show the `(HTTP proxy: 1.1.2.3:9191)` message. But when it is trying to download the packages, it just bypass the proxy (and I don't know why) as show the message `(no proxy)` in the end of the second and third lines

So my question is, how I have to configure SonarQube for use with proxy?

NOTE: this question is similar to [SonarQube Proxy Configuration, Tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495468/sonarqube-proxy-configuration-tricky) but I think is not the same I can see the plugins and updates list, but can download them, so I think is not duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that sonar configuration file allows you to set up http proxy but it has nothing to do with `https` or `ftp`, then those update sites with https fail.

So the solution:
Add to **sonar.properties**

```
sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts=-Dhttps.proxyHost=10.1.2.3 -Dhttps.proxyPort=9191 -Dhttps.proxyUser=theuser -Dhttps.proxyPassword=thepassword
```

Answer (score 0):

We also faced this issue, when we were using IP address of proxy. When I switched to proxy name, it worked fine.

```
DEBUG web[o.s.a.u.HttpDownloader$BaseHttpDownloader$HttpInputSupplier] Download: http://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties (HTTP proxy: www-proxy5.in.my.com:11)
DEBUG web[o.s.a.u.HttpDownloader$BaseHttpDownloader$HttpInputSupplier] Download: http://downloads.sonarsource.com/plugins/org/codehaus/sonar-plugins/python/sonar-python-plugin/1.5/sonar-python-plugin-1.5.jar (HTTP proxy: www-proxy5.in.my.com:11)
```

Try using a proxy name rather IP address and we were not doing any authentication so left the user/password blank. Please post entire stacktrace if this does not work.

Comment: Thank you man Rigth now I am far from work, I will try it and let you know

Comment: I changed the proxy IP address for the proxy domain name and the problem still the same

Comment: Can you pls share the complete stacktrace and content of sonnar.properties file.

Comment: Hi guys, sorry I found the solution and didn't know how to answer (If just a comment or a answer, but it was my own question, so I don't know D=) . The problem was that sonar configuration file allows you to set up `http` proxy but it has nothing to do with `https` or `ftp`, then those update sites with https fail. So the solution; add `sonar.web.javaAdditionalOpts=-Dhttps.proxyHost=10.1.2.3 -Dhttps.proxyPort=9191 -Dhttps.proxyUser=theuser -Dhttps.proxyPassword=thepassword
` to the sonar.properties file. Should I answer my own question ?