# Run sonarQube maven plugin into pipeline jenkins

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-pipeline, maven-plugin, sonarqube-scan

I try to create pipeline Job into Jenkins.

1. I create Jenkins Job
2. I create pipeline Jenkinsfile file
3. I add this Jenkinsfile into my Git repository
4. I have another repository with my maven application
5. Into application `pom.xml` I have

   ```
   <build>
       <pluginManagement>
           <plugins>
               <plugin>
                   <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                   <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                   <version>3.4.0.905</version>
               </plugin>
           </plugins>
       </pluginManagement>
   </build>
   ```

6. So I have this kind of pipeline:

   ```
   pipeline{
   agent any
       stages{
           stage("git connection"){
               steps{
                   git credentialsId: 'd96d4abcaa0-a067-bda2a0a942f7', 
                   url: 'http://admin@localhost:3080/annGROUP/assemblyJOB'
               }
           }
           stage("maven clean") {
               steps{
                   withMaven() {
                       sh 'mvn clean'
                   }   
               }
           }
           stage("maven install") {
               steps{
                   withMaven() {
                       sh 'mvn install'
                   }
               }
           }
           stage("maven sonar") {
               steps{
                   withMaven() {
                       sh 'mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://SONARHOST/sonar/ -Dsonar.credentials=login:password'
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

7. I have problem with last step:

   ```
   steps{
       withMaven() {
            sh 'mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://SONARHOST/sonar/ -Dsonar.credentials=login:password'
       }
   }
   ```
8. Stacktrace:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.4.0.905:sonar
>   (default-cli) on project testAssembly: Unable to load component class
>   org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BatchPluginInstaller: Unable to load
>   component class org.sonar.home.cache.FileCache: Unable to load
>   component class org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalSettings: Unable to
>   load component class
>   org.sonar.scanner.protocol.input.GlobalRepositories: Error 407 on
>   http://SONARHOST/sonar/batch/global

How can I fix ths?

Comment: '407' looks like an HTTP response code. Have you looked up what it means?

Comment: Looks like you did not set proxy config on your server. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20495468/sonarqube-proxy-configuration-tricky